# Traverse an array in JSON using Jackson using ArrayNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to traverse through this JSON using Jackson.

ObjectNode dd = (ObjectNode) definition.get("views").get("joins");

It returns a NullPointerException.

Tried out multiple ways using ArrayNode also but the error still exists.

Basically it is not able to find the ArrayNode "joins".

Can someone help and let me know where I am making the mistake?

Below is the JSON.

```
  {
        "id": "SmartVitalSigns",
        "type": {
            "Age": "12"
        },
        "views": [{
            "type": "Ind",
            "query": {
                "type": "query",
                "name": "Height"
            },
            "joins": [{
                "type": "in",
                "definition": "Obj",
                "link": {
                    "type": "element",
                    "definition": "Nation"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main object, the value of `views` is an array. If you know that it has only one element, you can access it via `definition.get("views").elements().next().get("joins")`.

Note that `joins` is an array, too, so you also need to access its element(s) in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
JsonNode ss = (JsonNode) definition.get("views").elements().next().get("joins").elements().next();
  System.out.println(ss.get("type").asText());
Still gives me an error :(

Comment: For me, the `asText()` call correctly returns `in`. Try printing `System.out.println(ss.get("type"));`